# Cron execute ruby file on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron

How to run cron to execute ruby file on ubuntu?

I'm try this syntax on my terminal :

```
crontab -e
57 10 * * * mkdir -p /home/user/foo/
```

this work perfectly folder foo it's created, but how to execute ruby file using cron?
example i have file on "/home/user/abc.rb", how to make this work?

Comment: just like you would run it from a command line...?

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on how you installed `ruby`.

If you want to use system ruby this will suffice.

```
57 10 * * * ruby /home/user/abc.rb
```

But if you installed ruby from `rbenv`, you have to load proper environment.

```
57 10 * * * bash -c 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; ruby /home/user/abc.rb'
```

Comment: i'm using rvm by the way, and i'don't know why i'm get error like this "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2: Permission denied"

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about `rvm`. You should add information in your question that you are using `rvm` and which permissions have the directory `/home/user/.rvm`, so that other people can help you.